# Bootstrap, columns are not aligned

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a grid with 3 columns and on row, in each of these columns there is a container. But I have a weird display : 
[image]

A normal display should be like this :

[image]

My 3 columns are : My navbar, my card grid and my "zoom" on one card. I want my navbar AND my "zoom" column to be fixed-top, so when I scroll down, only my grid is scrolling. So I put the attribut fixed-top for my navbar, and it works. But when I do the same things for my zoom column, I get the weird layout.

My html body :

```html
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar .fixed-top" data-offset="50">
        <div class="container-fill main_container">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-sm-2 side_bar_n">  <!-- Nav bar here -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion fixed-top" id="accordionSidebar">
                        ........ 

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">  <!-- Card grid -->
                    <div class="container grid_container">
                      <h1>Recherche de carte</h1>
                      <div class="row no-gutters">
                          <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
                            ........
                          <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"> <!-- Card display -->
                    <div class="container-fluid fixed-top">
                        <div class="card card_body">
                          <img class="card-img-top rounded" src="cards/368262.jpg" alt="Card image">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Rythme of the Wild</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Creature spells you control can't be countered.
                                                    NonToken creatures you control have riot (+1/+1 or haste when entering the battlefield.)</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `container-fluid fixed-top` from card display div...

Also increase the card `col` as `col-sm-3`

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ws36zpuq/)

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar .fixed-top" data-offset="50">
  <div class="container-fill main_container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm-2 side_bar_n">
        <!-- Nav bar here -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion fixed-top" id="accordionSidebar">
          ........

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <!-- Card grid -->
        <div class="container grid_container">
          <h1>Recherche de carte</h1>
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
            ........
            <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!-- Card display -->
        <div class="">
          <div class="card card_body">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded" src="cards/368262.jpg" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Rythme of the Wild</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Creature spells you control can't be countered. NonToken creatures you control have riot (+1/+1 or haste when entering the battlefield.)</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want my "zoom" column to be fixed

Comment: Thank you but when I do this, my card doesn't stay fixed. When I scroll, my navbar isn't scrolling but my "zoom" column and my card grid are scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float-right` class to the column that you want on right and also add `clearfix` class to all divs classed `container`. I have done this in the following code.

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar .fixed-top" data-offset="50">
        <div class="container-fill main_container clearfix">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-sm-2 side_bar_n">  <!-- Nav bar here -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion fixed-top" id="accordionSidebar">
                        ........ 
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">  <!-- Card grid -->
                    <div class="container grid_container clearfix">
                      <h1>Recherche de carte</h1>
                      <div class="row no-gutters">
                          <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
                            ........
                          <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="cards/287044.jpg" class="rounded grid_space img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 float-right"> <!-- Card display -->
                    <div class="container-fluid fixed-top clearfix">
                        <div class="card card_body">
                          <img class="card-img-top rounded" src="cards/368262.jpg" alt="Card image">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Rythme of the Wild</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Creature spells you control can't be countered.NonToken creatures you control have riot (+1/+1 or haste when entering the battlefield.)</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I did that but it stay the same whatever I do

Comment: Try using a single container classed div [ you have multiple divs with container class, some with container-fluid ] that has multiple rows with multiple columns and add the required classes to the columns.